# What keyboard shortcuts exist for Notes app is OS X?

Tags: macos, notes.app

I can do cmd-N to create a new note.  What I'd like to learn how to do is:

- get the cursor in the search field, then use up down arrows with enter to select the right note
- it would be great to also cycle through notes with the keyboard, similar to cmd+shift+[ and cmd+shift+] in Chrome

How can I learn to do these things?

Comment: This great utility (it's free!) is really helpful: http://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet

Comment: I am also looking for a keyboard shortcut to cycle through notes with keyboard.

Comment: The list of shortcuts are in Apple's docs:
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25823?locale=en_US

Answer (score 6):

The app I use for this is [CheatSheet](http://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/)  since some shortcuts come from the system (screen shot, etc..), some come from third party apps, and some are from the app itself.

I count 51 keys active in Notes on my Mac, so I'm not going to list them all. Yours are probably different than mine, since I have third party apps that have services with default keys enabled.

The movement request is best served by [Mouse Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_keys) - which came from X11 days and has been chosen/implemented as Apple's accessibility solution for using a number pad instead of the mouse/trackpad for you to navigate to the search field.

- https://www.apple.com/accessibility/osx/
- http://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/

Answer (score 1):

- to get the cursor on the search bar you can press the 'Note List Search...' shortcut (cmd+option+f)
- to focus on the Notes list, you can go to the search bar first by pressing cmd+option+f, and then press tab. That will bring your focus on the list, but i didnt figure out a way to bring the focus to the note from the notes list.

Answer (score 0):

I use [KeyCue](http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/), it works in all apps; it's similar to [@bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/206322/123620)'s solution but it's not free.
If you just wanna try is out you can download it from the website, or you can kickass.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/), I added a Cmd-ArrowUp shortcut to perform a click (400, 50) pixels from the top-left window corner.
Not free, but has saved me a *lot* of time over the years. Unfortunately its services are required more and more often :-/

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to jump from editing text in a note to moving between notes or folders directly. But if you press Command+1 twice you will go into attachment view and back out, and focus will move onto the notes list.

From here you can use tab and arrow keys to access different notes and folders and also the search field. Pressing return moves the focus to editing the note currently being displayed.